# p-nilpotency and normality

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ be a sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ such that $N_G(P)$ is not $p$-nilpotent, Then why $N_G(P)$ is non-normal in $G$?

Comment: $S_3$ with $p=3$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P$ char $N_G(P) \leq G$, we see that $N_G(P) \unlhd G$ if and only if $P \unlhd G$. Now $P$ is a normal Hall subgroup of $N_G(P)$, hence with the help of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem it always has a complement. This implies that $N_G(P)$ is $p$-nilpotent if and only if $N_G(P)=P \times K$, for some $K \unlhd N_G(P)$. Combining the two in your exercise: if $P \unlhd G$, then $G=N_G(P)=P \times K$, for some normal subgroup $K$ of $G$. However, in general with a $p$-Sylow subgroup that is not a direct factor, the statement is not true. As pointed out by Derek Holt, a counterexample would be $S_3$ with $p=3$.

Comment: Please explain since i have to solve this problem

Comment: I dont understand, please xplain Dear prof. Nicky Hekster!